# Baking shadows onto a plane with no image texture in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

I'm in cycles render and I made a scene with a bunch of lightbulbs (see Blenderguru's tutorial. I did the same thing) and I have a Mac with not so decent specs, and I want to speed up the rendering. I am wondering if I could bake the shadows and light onto the plane that all the objects are on. It has a material but not a texture.

Comment: Baking means rendering! So you won't save much time baking them separately. Unless you have a specific creative reason to bake your shadows independently, for example to post process them before compositing, you'd better stick with single pass rendering and save in composition complexity. Also since you are experimenting with lighting, you probably want your shadows to be the actual result or your lights setup. Btw are you planning to keep all your objects static and may be just experiment with changing their color or material?

Comment: Everything is static except for the camera. No colors or anything are changing. the only keyframes are for the cameras location on the Y axis. Nothing else